# Getting my ETH back after Sending transaction

Tags: wallet-transfer

I took the plunge and bought some ETH without really knowing how it really worked. I like to learn while doing!
I reached a point where I tried to send ETH from my Exodus Wallet into Ethernet Wallet (which I was told it was named MIST, a name I never saw), but when accessing my EW, it starts to Sync (I assume that it needs to be synced in order to see my transaction in it). 
The thing is that it takes a million years to sync, and takes a lot of space in the disk. I want to go back to where I started (i.e. get the ETH back to Exodus).
1) Is this possible? How can I retrieve the ETH?
2) Do all the wallets take this long to sync? Or is it just a precautionary (?) meassure to make EW more secure?
Thanks in advance!
Julio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full node must sync the whole blockchain to ensure that there is nothing 'fishy' happening anywhere on the chain. i.e. To ensure that the version you have is correct (according to the versions everybody else has)

If you transferred the ETH to another address, you can view the new address's balance on something like https://etherscan.io/. This way you can prove to yourself that the funds aren't lost, simply assigned to a new account.

Providing you have the key for the 'new' and 'old' accounts, you still 'own' all of the ETH, you simply have it stored in multiple locations. This is not a bad thing, as you get more ETH/BTC, you should split it over different accounts. This way if an account is compromised, you won't lose all of your token holdings!

Comment: Feel free to upvote/mark correct if this helped. Cheers